# Capture one or more occurrences of a regex expression (as denoted by characters outside the capture group)?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
    var title = '[string A][string B] the rest of the title'
    var myRegexp = /\[(.*)\]/g;
    var match = myRegexp.exec(title);
    console.log(match);  // prints: 'string A][string B', and not: 'string A', 'string B'
```

I'm looking for a regex expression to capture one or more strings denoted by a pair of square brackets (in javascript). How do I accomplish this?

*alternate title case include:* '[string A] some text [string B]' and '[string A] and no string b'

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) or use a negated character class instead of `.*` :

```
/\[.*?\]/g
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/tV9qJ3/1

or

```
/\[[^\]]*\]/g
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/tV9qJ3/2

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `exec` in a loop for multiple matches with this regex:

```
var re = /\[([^\]]*)/g; 
var str = '[string A][string B] the rest of the title';
var m;
var matches = [];

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex)
        re.lastIndex++;
    matches.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(matches);
//=> ["string A", "string B"]
```